# Stash, Parsingorder (?) and conditionals if content exists

Tags: templates, stash, parse-order

I am sorry to ask this, but I am stuck here.

I must change (on two places) a css class if a channel entree exists.
If yes, the class must be unit-70, if no, unit-90.
This code below does not work, I do not know why. (when setting stash hardcoded it works as expected)

```
{exp:stash:set name="content_block_mid" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="news_flash"
    disable="categories|category_fields|pagination|member_data"
    dynamic="no"
}
    {if no_results}unit-80{/if}
    {if count >= 1}unit-70{/if}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction, obviously I am missing something here. I tried many options, but got lost because nothing works. This seems to me the simpliest of solutions, but I fail even here.
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might try using '[unprefix](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset%7D#unprefix---string-)' for the nested channel entry tags:

```
{exp:stash:set 
    name="content_block_mid" 
    parse_tags="yes" 
    parse_conditionals="yes"
    unprefix="my_prefix"
}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="news_flash"
        disable="categories|category_fields|pagination|member_data"
        dynamic="no"
    }
        {if my_prefix:no_results}unit-80{/if}
        {if my_prefix:count >= 1}unit-70{/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```